# MVC IgnoreRoute /?_escaped_fragment_= to continue Reverse Proxy with IIS ARR

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

***Technical Information***

- `AngularJS` single page app
- `Umbraco 7.3.0` website, extended to register routes via [`Umbraco.Core.ApplicationEventHandler`](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Events/Application-Startup) in a separate class library

***Scenario***

I have an `AngularJS` single page app (SPA) that I'm trying to pre-render via an external `PhantomJS` service.

I want `MVC`'s route handler to ignore the route `/?_escaped_fragment_={fragment}`, so the [request can be handled directly by `ASP.NET`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15381189/912545) and thus passed on to `IIS` to proxy the request.

***In Theory***

- `Umbraco` is built on `ASP.NET MVC`.
- Routes are configurable via [`System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15381189/912545) class.
- When extending `Umbraco` with custom routes, any routes configured via the [`System.Web.Routing.RouteTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will take precedence over Umbraco routes, thus never being handled by `Umbraco`**
- Possible methods for my scenario

  - [`public void Ignore(string url)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routetable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or
  - [`public void Ignore(string url, object constraints)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784609%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**I could be wrong. As far as I'm aware, custom routing takes precedence as it's done before the `Umbraco` routes are registered. However I'm unsure whether telling `MVC` to ignore a route would also prevent Umbraco from handling that route.

***In Practise***

I have attempted to ignore the routes with the following:

*Attempt one:*

```
routes.Ignore("?_escaped_fragment_={*pathInfo}");
```

This throws an error: `The route URL cannot start with a '/' or '~' character and it cannot contain a '?' character.`

*Attempt two:*

```
routes.Ignore("{*escapedfragment}", new { escapedfragment = @".*\?_escaped_fragment_=\/(.*)" });
```

This didn't result in an error, however Umbraco still picked up the request and handed me back my root page. [Regex validation on Regexr](http://regexr.com/3crdp).

***Questions***

- Can `MVC` actually ignore a route based on its `query string`?
- Is my knowledge of `Umbraco`'s routing correct?
- Is my `regex` correct?
- Or am I missing something?

Comment: I think [this one is related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941967/how-do-i-route-a-url-with-a-querystring-in-asp-net-mvc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in routing behavior doesn't take the query string into consideration. However, routing is extensible and can be based on query string if needed.

The simplest solution is to make a custom `RouteBase` subclass that can detect your query string, and then use the `StopRoutingHandler` to ensure the route doesn't function.

```
public class IgnoreQueryStringKeyRoute : RouteBase
{
    private readonly string queryStringKey;

    public IgnoreQueryStringKeyRoute(string queryStringKey)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(queryStringKey))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("queryStringKey is required");
        this.queryStringKey = queryStringKey;
    }

    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext.Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Any(x => x == queryStringKey))
        {
            return new RouteData(this, new StopRoutingHandler());
        }

        // Tell MVC this route did not match
        return null;
    }

    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        // Tell MVC this route did not match
        return null;
    }
}
```

## Usage

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        // This route should go first
        routes.Add(
            name: "IgnoreQuery",
            item: new IgnoreQueryStringKeyRoute("_escaped_fragment_"));


        // Any other routes should be registered after...

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```